# Game. Order array of String

Tags: java

**Statement**
The game consists of ordering the elements that they give you. There are in total 8 elements and 2 holes.

You have to sort it and the method for when the unordered array matches any of the possible options.

The only restriction is that you have to order it 2 by two, that is, in each iteration you have to move two elements at the same time.

my code:

```
boolean  truee;
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    array.add(0, "A");
    array.add(1, "B");
    array.add(2, "A");
    array.add(3, "B");
    array.add(4, "A");
    array.add(5, "B");
    array.add(6, "A");
    array.add(7, "B");
    array.add(8, null);
    array.add(9, null);

    System.out.print(array);
}

private static ArrayList<String> order(ArrayList<String> array) {
    boolean istrue = true;
    
    //...States
    do {
        
    }while(istrue);
    
    return array;
}
```

I don't really know how to make the function so that it orders the array.

```
this solution over paper.
A B A B A B A B 0 0
A 0 0 B A B A B B A
A A B B 0 0 A B B A
A A B B B B A 0 0 A
0 0 B B B B A A A A
```

Comment: In the description you have just pasted the template for the logic as the sorting seems to be incomplete. Please try at least to complete the sorting and then check if the result is as you expect to be. If it is not, then use the debugger to solve the issue. If it does not help you, then look for the answer on SO. Do not expect that someone will send you complete solution.

Comment: @marcin.programuje I'm trying to program it, but I'm just not able to imagine it. I know how to solve it on paper, but not by programming it. I've changed the statement and put the solution I have on paper.I don't know how to do the function that commands me the arraylist by taking two elements at once.

Comment: Is the null in the Java code a representation of ```0``` from your paper?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can benefit from the `java.util.Comparator` class. To sort it the way you want to, firstly you have to deal with null values by using the following function:
`Comparator.nullsFirst(...)` - it will move null values to first places of your list. but it will give you a natural ordering. Your expected result needs to be reverted so the next step will be to use the `Comparator.reverseOrder()` function - it will make a 'B' standing before 'A'.
To use described operators invoke the `sort` method on your list.

Example usage:

```
list.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```